# This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up

Tags: android, crashlytics, crash-reports, google-fabric

but i have some problem at first i have a orange check image in right of app package name 
[image]

and i have this error in Application class

```
 Caused by: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
                                                               install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
                                                                   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:233)
                                                                   at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.onPreExecute(CrashlyticsCore.java:207)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.onPreExecute(InitializationTask.java:44)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:611)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.PriorityAsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(PriorityAsyncTask.java:43)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize(Kit.java:69)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.initializeKits(Fabric.java:440)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.init(Fabric.java:384)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.setFabric(Fabric.java:342)
                                                                   at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with(Fabric.java:333)
                                                                   at com.atyno.app.VolleyApplication.onCreate(VolleyApplication.java:78)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1036)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6317)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

thanks 
my fault

```
 productFlavors {
        dev {
            minSdkVersion 21
            dimension 'atyno'
            resConfigs ("en", "xxxhdpi")
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
        }
```

and exactly

```
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
```

after remove that its ok.

Comment: thanks, i wasted 4 hours on this silly mistake